# Multi mysql query using two different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue writing a query. I have two tables I want to pull data from, sales and calls. There is a column in both tables where a phone number is recorded, as well as a date column. I can do the JOIN just fine to match calls to sales, however I want to also show entries from both tables that don't match. Basically on a single page show the rows that match from both tables, then the rows that didn't match from each table separately.

Here is the JOIN query:

```
SELECT 
   sales.*, 
   calls.* 
FROM `sales` 
JOIN `calls` 
    ON sales.TelephoneNo = calls.TelephoneNo 
WHERE (
       sales.OrderDate >= '$MyStartDATE' 
   AND sales.OrderDate <= '$MyEndDATE'
) AND (
       calls.CallDate >= '$MyStartDATE' 
   AND calls.CallDate <= '$MyEndDATE'
) ORDER BY sales.OrderDate
```

Comment: You are possibly looking for a [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to use <> operator instead = to show **not matched** results

```
SELECT 
   sales.*, 
   calls.* 
FROM `sales` 
JOIN `calls` 
    ON sales.TelephoneNo <> calls.TelephoneNo 
WHERE (
       sales.OrderDate >= '$MyStartDATE' 
   AND sales.OrderDate <= '$MyEndDATE'
) AND (
       calls.CallDate >= '$MyStartDATE' 
   AND calls.CallDate <= '$MyEndDATE'
) ORDER BY sales.OrderDate
```

**UPDATE**

If you use LEFT JOIN Instead of JOIN it makes difference ?

Try this code

```
SELECT sales.*, 
       calls.* 
FROM   `sales` 
       LEFT JOIN `calls` 
              ON sales.telephoneno <> calls.telephoneno 
WHERE  sales.orderdate >= '$MyStartDATE' 
       AND sales.orderdate <= '$MyEndDATE' 
       AND calls.calldate >= '$MyStartDATE' 
       AND calls.calldate <= '$MyEndDATE' 
ORDER  BY sales.orderdate
```

Comment: I tried that option however what I got was one row from the call table repeated for each row of the sales table. So a 200 row sales table matched to the call table with 300 resulted in over 5000 results.

Comment: Because it's almost similar to a cross join

Comment: A left join makes little difference. you'll only get more records in the result

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support full joins, you'll need to combine left and right join with union

```
SELECT
    s.OrderDate,
    PhoneNumber,
    s.something fake,
    IF(c.PhoneNumber IS NULL, 'Sales', 'Both') match_from,
    IF(c.PhoneNumber IS NULL, 0, 1) has_match
FROM
    sales s
LEFT JOIN
    calls c
    USING (PhoneNumber)
WHERE
    s.OrderDate BETWEEN '$MyStartDATE' AND '$MyEndDATE'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
    c1.CallDate,
    PhoneNumber,
    'fake',
    IF(s1.PhoneNumber IS NULL, 'Call', 'Both'),
    IF(s1.PhoneNumber IS NULL, 0, 1)
FROM
    sales s1
RIGHT JOIN
    calls c1
    USING (PhoneNumber)
WHERE
    c1.CallDate BETWEEN '$MyStartDATE' AND '$MyEndDATE'
ORDER BY has_match
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the rest of the data from the other columns? I know that each table has a different number of columns so perhaps that may not be possible with your solution. I will say it's a lot cleaner than what I was coming up with.

Comment: Yes, you can add 'fake' colums to the SELECT clause for the table where you have less columns. I will update my answer with an example.